# Playing a random frame inside MovieClip with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, random, frame, movieclip

I have a movie clip (goalkeeper) with different positions in different frames (inside), I would like to play a random frame after executing  a function  to make the goalkeeper move to a determinate position, there are 6 frames with 6 different positions so I need to play 1 position randomly, this is the code that should go to the random number after ball is kicked:

```
  function moveBall()
  { 
var targetX:Number = mouseX;
var targetY:Number = mouseY;
var angle = Math.atan2(targetY,targetX);
ball.x =  mouseX + Math.cos(angle);
ball.y =  mouseY + Math.sin(angle) ;
ballRotation = true;

if (ballRotation==true)
{


    goalkeeper_mc.gotoAndStop( Random Frame);//Here is when I need to go and play the random frame everytime function is executed


}
```

Thanks a lot for your help guys,  sorry for bothering again, I searched the web for some examples but I found many of them really complicated for a newbie like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer a following code.

you must randomize from 1 frame to last Frame.

`Math.random ()` of the range is greater than 0 and less than 1(floating-value). by use it implements available.

---

```
function moveBall()
{ 
    var targetX:Number = mouseX;
    var targetY:Number = mouseY;
    var angle = Math.atan2(targetY,targetX);
    ball.x =  mouseX + Math.cos(angle);
    ball.y =  mouseY + Math.sin(angle) ;
    ballRotation = true;

    if (ballRotation==true)
    {
        goalkeeper_mc.gotoAndStop(int(Math.random * (goalkeeper_mc.totalFrames)+1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey bitmapdata.com, good to hear from you again pal! Hey as you see I needed to get back to my old moveball function, the onenterframe stuff was causing one of my functions (if statement) to be triggered many times (1 time by frame I guess) and I was unable to fix it despite the fact I received a lot of help.  Thanks again for coming back to the rescue!!!

Comment: It is a very great pleasure helped you. Are always welcome. :)

Comment: Hey guys what about if I need to choose only between frames 45,46,47,48,49,50,51,60? the thing is that I have another animation between frames 1 and 44 (the goalkeeper is moving to distract the player as in real life) thanks a lot pals!

Comment: `45~60` => `int(Math.random()*16)+45`

Comment: Sorry did not get it Bitmapdata, well to be correct the frames I need to choose are 43,44,45,46,47,48, so would it be like this goalkeeper_mc.gotoAndStop(43~48 => int(Math.random()*6)+43)); ? Sorry if I’m messing everything pal, my mind is kind of blocked, its almost 3 am down here. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
goalkeeper_mc.gotoAndStop(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * goalkeeper_mc.totalFrames));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help strille, will try both options and will save the info to have it handy in future games, this place is the best man, everybody is always willing to help, thanks again.